# How to force recomposition in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition

I wrote utility functions to request/check permissions in Composables (using [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal)).

```
data class PermissionHandlerValue(
    val hasPermission: (String) -> Boolean,
    val hasPermissions: (Array<out String>) -> Array<Boolean>,
    val requestPermission: (String) -> Unit,
    val requestPermissions: (Array<out String>) -> Unit
)

val LocalPermissionHandler = compositionLocalOf<PermissionHandlerValue> { error("No implementation provided!") }

@Composable
fun ProvidePermissionHandler(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalPermissionHandler provides permissionHandlerImpl()) {
        content()
    }
}

@Composable
fun permissionHandlerImpl(): PermissionHandlerValue {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {}

    val hasPermission: (String) -> Boolean = { ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }
    val hasPermissions: (Array<out String>) -> Array<Boolean> = { it.map { permission -> hasPermission(permission) }.toTypedArray() }

    val requestPermission: (String) -> Unit = { launcher.launch(arrayOf(it)) }
    val requestPermissions: (Array<out String>) -> Unit = { launcher.launch(it) }

    return PermissionHandlerValue(hasPermission, hasPermissions, requestPermission, requestPermissions)
}

@Composable
fun RequirePermission(permission: String, fallback: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val permissionHandler = LocalPermissionHandler.current
    if (permissionHandler.hasPermission(permission))
        content()
    else if (fallback != null)
        fallback()
}
```

It works fine, I can request and check permissions. The problem is that its not reactive, here's an example:

```
setContent {
    ProvidePermissionHandler {
        val permissionHandler = LocalPermissionHandler.current

        RequirePermission(
            permission = Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            fallback = { 
                Button(onClick = { permissionHandler.requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) 
                }) { 
                    Text("Request permission") 
                }
            }
        ) {
            ContactsList() 
        }
    }
}
```

This composable(`RequirePermission`) will only render `ContactsList` if the `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS` was granted, Otherwise the `fallback` component is rendered with a button that when clicked will request the permission.

After `permissionHandler.requestPermission()` is called and I grant the permission on the screen the `fallback` still shows, instead of the `ContactsList` (I have to re-open the app to show it).

Basically the condition in `RequirePermission()` is not checked again because there is no recomposition. How can I force `RequirePermission()` to recompose?

Comment: You need to update some state that your composable will react to.